# capturing the last value in UISlider while isContinuous is true

Tags: swift, uislider

I have a programatically set UISlider, where the property

```
slider.isContinuous = true
```

This suits the game play I use.  As the slider moves, several things change in my user interface.
Now, I'd also like to catch the last value changed in the slider as a discrete value (the same behaviour as if `.isContinuous` was set to `false`).  Has someone found a way to do this?

Comment: Can't you just store, in the UIControl delegate, the rounded value and compare it with previously store value, and if different call whatever function or routine of choice?

Comment: Better solution below. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    @IBAction func sliderChanged(_ sender: UISlider, forEvent event: UIEvent) {
        if let touchEvent = event.allTouches?.first {
            switch touchEvent.phase {
            case .began:
                debugPrint("touch begin")
                debugPrint("current value: \(sender.value)")
            case .ended:
                debugPrint("touch end")
                debugPrint("current value: \(sender.value)")
                // record current value, save it in the view state
            default:
                debugPrint("touch continue")
            }
        }
    }
```

The main idea is save the value when it reach the .ended case, and ignore other cases that are inrelevant.

update: https://github.com/0x00Zhoujialei/DiscreteIsContinuous is the demo I've just updated, you can run the demo and check the result on the console.

Comment: Thanks!. For completeness `slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.sliderChanged(_:forEvent:)), for: .valueChanged)` worked for me to call the function